# Please answer the following questions urgently

Tags: sharia, prophet-lut

What is the act of lut’s people? I know it’s homosexuality but what exactly

Also, I want to ask what is the meaning of sodomy in Islam? Does it include oral sex as well?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q6A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. These are too many questions in one post and at least some of them are already answered on the site (see for example [in our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)). This site is not for urgent questions as we are not a fatwa site. Further you should use meaningful question titles.

Answer (score -2):

The act of the people of Lut (as) was homosexuality and being gay and men having anal sex with one another and women having sex with other women. Homosexuality is such a big crime that Allah destroyed the nation of Lut (as) for doing this kind of sin. The act of the people of Lut (as) is something that Allah (swt) does not like at all! Allah (swt) was very angry with those people which is why he sent 3 different punishments to completely destroy that nation. Being gay is the biggest sin to Allah (swt). However, Allah (swt) is the most merciful, so if someone repents from the act of homosexuality and asks Allah for forgiveness, Allah will forgive them. So never despair in the mercy of Allah (swt) as he is the most forgiving and the most merciful. No matter how big our sins are and no matter what we’ve done, if we sincerely ask Allah to forgive us then he loves to forgive us. As for oral sex between a man and a woman, this is not sodomy but still it it is totally haram. We use our tongue for good things like reciting the Quran, not for filthy gross stuff.

For more information, see the Quran,

Surah Al-A’raf: 80

Hud: 82-83

A-Shu’ara: 165-166

Al-Anbiya’: 74

And see the following links

The story of Prophet Lut (as) - https://youtu.be/n6dsA7PBECo

What happened when the Ancient Greeks started to act like the people of Lut (as) - https://youtu.be/z_nwy7NpMl0

Comment: "Women having sex with other women"- Do you have ANY evidence for this? That the people of Lut(as)'s act was women having sex with other women? And how can that even be considered sex islamically? Of course that is haram but you must provide evidence for this.